# How to get an Iron or Coal Mine

Tags: ios, a-dark-room

I keep trying to get an Iron Mine, "I", or a Coal Mine, "C", with no luck.
Can anyone tell me how to get a mine?

Answer (score 2):

The first time you go to the mine while in the map (as you said, **I** and **C** icons), if you manage to defeat all the monsters, you will be able to get the mined materials the mine has in that moment.

From that moment you can send slaves to the mines in the **Village** menu.

Remember that, in order to get the things you manage to achieve in your trip, you have to return to your village without dying.

Comment: I went to 3 different C's and never got any mine or could send any miner there. Something seems wrong...

Comment: @schulbrezel You have to return alive to your town

Comment: @schulbrezel it has been a while since I played, but if you complete the mine and return to the village, there should be a path of "#" to the mine on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You don't find a miner. You find the mine, fight the beasts or scavengers within and then return to your village alive after the notification that "The mine is safe for working in" comes up. Just make sure you have a boatload of cured meat and that you know where your village is and that the cave is safe for working in.